# Pytest fixtures in different subfolders are not recognized

Tags: python, pytest

If I have a repo with following code structures:

```
repo/
-- test
  -- preprocess
     -- conftest.py
     -- test_preprocess.py
  -- classifier
     -- conftest.py
     -- test_classifier.py
```

How can I call a fixture that is defined in `test/preprocess/conftest.py` inside `test_classifier.py`? I tried this and my fixture was not recognized. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
repo/
-- test
  -- conftest.py <--- for fixtures shared for all subfolders' tests
  -- preprocess
     -- conftest.py
     -- test_preprocess.py
  -- classifier
     -- conftest.py
     -- test_classifier.py
```

See [Sharing Fixtures Across Files](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html?highlight=conftest#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files)